# RxJava android Flowable retryWhen doesn't calling onError when occured error at last retry

Tags: android, rx-java2

my Flowable is returned from Retrofit ApiService, i attempt the below code to implement error retry mechanism, i wish it can call onError function when occurred error at last retry.

```
   flowable.retryWhen(throwableFlowable -> {
                AtomicInteger retryCounter = new AtomicInteger();
                return throwableFlowable
                    .takeWhile(throwable -> retryCounter.getAndIncrement() < 3);
            })
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .unsubscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(onNext, onError, onComplete, onSubscribe);
```

but it doesn't call the onError function when occurred error at last retry. I try add doOnError(onError) before retryWhen, but it doesn't work. Could anyone help me?

the RxJava is 2.2.19, the RxAndroid version is 2.1.1.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the inner flow signal an `onError`. If you want this to be the last error from the main sequence, rethrow it in `takeWhile`:

```java
.takeWhile(throwable -> {
  if (retryCounter.getAndIncrement() < 3) {
    return true;
  }
  throw throwable;
})
```

**Edit:**
Alternatively, you could replace `takeWhile` with `flatMap` and signal a `Flowable.error`.

```java
flowable.retryWhen(throwableFlowable -> {
    AtomicInteger retryCounter = new AtomicInteger();
    return throwableFlowable
           .flatMap(throwable -> {
               if (retryCounter.getAndIncrement() < 3) {
                   return Flowable.just(1);
               }
               return Flowable.<Integer>error(throwable);
           });
})
```

Comment: thx first, but `throw throwable;` doesn't compile success because of Unhandled exception: java.lang.Throwable. So could i modify `throw throwable;` to `throw (Exception) throwable;` ? It can compile success, but i don't known it will whether or not occurr other error.

Comment: If you know for sure throwable can be cast to it. Otherwise wrap it: throw new Exception(throwable).